# how to use variables in a psql script

Tags: postgresql, psql

Here is my psql script, which does not work:

```
\set path '''c:\\server\\data\\''';
COPY paymentMethods (name,regexString) FROM :path+'paymentMethods.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true);
COPY priceLevels (name) FROM :path+'priceLevels.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false);
```

psql complains about the syntax error at the `+`

How can I change it so that it works, while having the actual path string mentioned just once?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to concatenate two strings with `+` operator, but the SQL operator for concatenation is `||`, with that information, you could think the expected result would be (**won't work**):

```
\set path '''c:\\server\\data\\'''
COPY paymentMethods (name,regexString) FROM :path || 'paymentMethods.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true);
COPY priceLevels (name) FROM :path || 'priceLevels.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false);
```

But! The `COPY` command expect a literal string for the path, not an expression, so you really should give the path. Notice it would work for commands like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, etc.

With that information, you can only use `psql` variables, as Pavel pointed, and concatenate the strings into a `psql`'s variable. A good solution is to use the `psql`'s `:'var'` syntax, that insert the variable as a string into the SQL expression:

```
\set path 'c:\\server\\data\\'
\set paymentMethodsPath :path 'paymentMethods.csv'
\set priceLevelsPath :path 'priceLevels.csv'
COPY paymentMethods (name,regexString) FROM :'paymentMethodsPath' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true);
COPY priceLevels (name) FROM :'priceLevels' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false);
```

Which will generate (will send to the PostgreSQL's server):

```
COPY paymentMethods (name,regexString) FROM E'c:\\server\\data\\paymentMethods.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true);
COPY priceLevels (name) FROM E'c:\\server\\data\\priceLevels.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false);
```

This `:'var'` syntax will not work on all `psql` versions (I don't recall now which one this was introduced), but for old versions you can easily use dollar-quoting:

```
\set path 'c:\\server\\data\\'
\set paymentMethodsPath :path 'paymentMethods.csv'
\set priceLevelsPath :path 'priceLevels.csv'
COPY paymentMethods (name,regexString) FROM $$:paymentMethodsPath$$ WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true);
COPY priceLevels (name) FROM $$:priceLevels$$ WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false);
```

Or escape into single-quotes:

```
\set path 'c:\\server\\data\\'
\set paymentMethodsPath 'E''':path'paymentMethods.csv'''
\set priceLevelsPath 'E''':path'priceLevels.csv'''
COPY paymentMethods (name,regexString) FROM :paymentMethodsPath WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER true);
COPY priceLevels (name) FROM :priceLevels WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER false);
```

That is it.

Answer (score 4):

psql has no operators. You can only place a variable (somewhere)

```
postgres=# \set var1 AAAA
postgres=# \set var2 BBBB
postgres=# \echo :var1:var2
AAAABBBB
postgres=# \echo :var1 :var2
AAAA BBBB
postgres-# \echo :var1'\\':var2
AAAA\BBBB

postgres=# \set mypath '/tmp'
postgres=# \set mypathx :mypath/x.csv
postgres=# \echo :mypathx
/tmp/x.csv
postgres=# copy fo from :'mypathx';
COPY 1
postgres=# \set mypathy :mypath/y.csv
postgres=# copy fo from :'mypathy';
COPY 1
```

Comment: So, your answer is that what I want is impossible in a psql script?