# Using an environment variable in a PSQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql, environment-variables

Is it possible to use a Linux environment variable inside a .sql file? I'm using the copy/select query to write to an output file, and I'll like to put that directory in a variable. So I want to do something like:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM a)
TO $outputdir/a.csv
```

Outputdir would be set in my environment. Is this possible?

Comment: _NB:_ As is, even if you did succeed in substituting the variable, it won't work as expected because COPY ... TO expects the output file path to be single quoted.  See here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can store the result of a shell command inside a `psql` variable like this:

```
\set afile `echo "$outputdir/a.csv"`
COPY (SELECT * FROM a) TO :'afile';
```

Another (better in my opinion) solution is to use only `psql` variables, see [this answer of mine about psql variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673208/how-to-use-variables-in-a-psql-script/18683163#18683163), which is similar to your example. A example for your case would be:

```
\set outputdir '/path/to/output'
\set afile :outputdir '/a.csv'
COPY (SELECT * FROM a) TO :'afile';
```

Note that, in the example, you need to set the variable inside the script file, but you can skip the first line if you set it when you call `psql`:

```sh
psql --set=outputdir="$outputdir" <conn parameters> -f /path/to/yourscript.sql
```

Comment: I was very excited about this answer, but it's not quite working for me. Using your first example, 'afile' just evaluates to 'echo "$outputdir/a.csv"'. Nothing inside the quotes is expanded.

Comment: The examples work for me on psql 9.2.4.  What version of psql are you using?

Comment: According to the [psql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html) for 9.0, you _should_ be able to use backquotes to return the output from the shell.  Thus, that should really not be outputting the echo part especially, and the variable ought to be subject to expansion as well.  Did you copy that code verbatim and are you typed it out manually, are sure you didn't maybe use a single quote rather than a backquote?

Comment: YES! Single quote is exactly what I used. Thanks so much for that insight!!

Comment: The `echo $outputdir` syntax for accessing environment variables works perfectly on Unix. On Windows a different incantation is required; see my answer below.

Comment: @matheusol @benjwadams I'm getting a syntax error. Can you advise? mydb=# set custom.authentication_password to `echo $AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD`;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: set custom.authentication_password to `echo $AUTHENTICATION_...

Comment: @EleanorHolley the problem in your case is that the SQL `set` command cannot receive a backtick directly, you need a psql `\set` command (with backslash) first, e.g.


    `\set authentication_password ‘echo "${AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD}"‘`
    then `set custom.authentication_password to :'authentication_password';`

(I couldn't escpae backticks in comments, so replace ‘ by ` around the echo above)

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work for your use case, provided you single quote the output file name as I mentioned.  It will escape any double quotes as well contained within the SQL.

```
psql -c "$(eval echo '"' $(<envvars.sql | sed 's/"/\\"/g') '"')"
```

Of course, note that if your file contains any dollar quoted variables, the shell is going to try to interpret as a variable, and your script will break, so you will need to escape any dollar signs you need preserved literally with a backslash.

See also the second snippet in the accepted answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/235738/how-do-i-substitute-environment-variables-when-i-ouput-a-file) for a possibly more robust answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct for PostgreSQL running on Unix. Under Windows a different incantation is required for obtaining the value of the environment variable from the CMD shell and for avoiding the carriage return returned by the echo command.

```
\set afile `set /p=%outputdir%/a.csv`
COPY (SELECT * FROM a) TO :'afile';
```