# Passing a list to an environment variable in PSQL

Tags: sql, bash, shell, psql

Following the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725880/using-an-environment-variable-in-a-psql-script): I created the following SQL script with psql variables:

```
--query.sql
select * from my_table 
where day=:'day' and state in (:'states')
```

I am executing the above SQL script over SSH using the following shell commands in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
day='2015-05-01'
state='CA'
ssh myserver "psql -A -q -F $'\t' -d my_db -o temp_file.csv --set=day=${day} --set=states=${state}" < 'query.sql'
```

The issue that I'm having is how to pass in a list of states.  If I wanted to pass in 3 states from the shell script like:

```
state="'CA','NY','WA'"
```

My database query will return back 0 rows.  What's the correct way to pass in a list of states from a shell script to a psql variable?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be not in the shell but in the SQL:

```
state in (:'states')
```

In most SQL varieties -- and AFAIK that includes Postgres -- the variable is a scalar.  It contains a single value, not a column (and not row, of course).  You want a list, but in SQL there's no such animal.  When you initialize it with

```
state="'CA','NY','WA'"
```

you're providing a string that happens to look a bit like a list.  SQL isn't fooled, though: it expects a scalar and by gum that's what it sees.  Since there's no state with that name, it returns you zero rows.

> What's the correct way to pass in a list of states

There are 3 common answers: the bad way, the OK way, and the right way.

- The insecure way is to construct the IN clause dynamically.
- The standard answer is to provide the values as a column.  You might be have table-valued variables at your disposal, or temporary tables.  Insert the state names into one, and do something like

`where state in ('select state from #states')`

- If that seems roundabout, the right answer may lie in the database itself.  Consider: is the list of states *arbitrary*, or do they have something in common?  Can that seemingly arbitrary list be produced from data in the database?  If they belong to some known region, or are under some aegis, or are the product of some prior history, that probably should be represented in the database.  If so, the problem is transformed from *providing* the list to *generating* it.  Your query becomes

`where state in ('select state from ... where ... = :criterion)`

Although I've never seen an explicit rationale, I suspect arbitrary lists aren't well supported in SQL because they usually can and should be avoided by design.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll get requests to generate reports for groups of states and there's no real unifying criterion.  I'm tempted to just use python so I can just manipulate a template file and insert `state in ('CA','NY','WA')` just using string tools.

Comment: Yup, that's option #1.  Depending on your environment, that can be perfectly fine or disastrous for security.  If you have control over the SQL and the state names are vetted, that's what I would do.  Else you're in for SQL injection from little Bobby Tables.  :-)